# Html.DropDownListFor grouping by bool - show string instead of bool value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm using the `Html.DropDownListFor()` to display a dropdown with data from a list. The list items have a boolean property called `IsPublic`, defining whether this item is public or not.

Here's how I define the dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLayout,
                    new SelectList(Model.Layout, "LayoutString", "LayoutName", "IsPublic", 1))
```

As you can see, I'm grouping by the property `IsPublic`. As expected, the grouping is done the following way, with the following naming of the groups:

[image]

Notice how the grouping is done by the boolean value (`true` and `false`).

Is there a way for me to display this grouping as a custom string, though still grouping on the boolean value? So if `IsPublic == true` display the grouping name as `Public` and vice versa `IsPublic == false` display grouping name as `Private`?

Comment: You can do this by creating a new `SelectListGroup` and setting its `Name` property, (based on the `bool` value) and then creating new `SelectListItem` and setting the `Group` property as described in the second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151572/constructing-a-select-list-with-optgroup-groups/37152663#37152663). You have not shown the model or what values it migh contain so bit hard to give a code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a get only property in your class, and use it for grouping.

```
public string DisplayPublic {
    get { return IsPublic ? "Public" : "Private"; }
}
```

Comment: Of course this is the solution. This works like a charm! Appreciate the help!