# jquery multiselect - grouping from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using a jquery multiselect plugin [https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect] and binding it dynamically with database values.

**HTML**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Classes, new SelectList(Model.Classes, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "classList" })
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#classList').multiselect({ enableClickableOptGroups: true });
```

The model in the view is a view model and contains a property for a `SelectList`

```
public class SearchControlViewModel 
{
    ....
    public SelectList Classes { get; set; }
}
```

and the code in the controller

```
SearchControlViewModel  model = new SearchControlViewModel()
{
    ....
    Classes = new SelectList(repClass.GetClassesByYear(23), "classID", "classname")
};
return View(model);
```

It works like a charm except for one thing - I want to add grouping/group header like `<optgroup>` does. How can I do that?

The `GetClassesByYear()` method used for generating the `SelectList` returns an object containing properties `int classID`, `string classname` and `string grade` and I want to be able to group the options by `grade`.

Comment: Are you using MVC-5 (which supports option grouping for `SelectListItem`)?

Comment: MVC 4 unfortunately

Comment: Then your out of luck (unless you generate the html manually) - your will need to upgrade (for an example, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151572/constructing-a-select-list-with-optgroup-groups))

Comment: can i do something like parse the generated html and then add groupopts myself? any hints/examples?

Comment: I guess you could pass model to the view indicating the groups and which option belongs in each group, and then assign that to a javascript variable, and then use javascript to build the `<optgroup>` and `<option> elements for `<select>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139110/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-samra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option groups are not supported in MVC-4, and you would need to upgrade to MVC-5 to make use out-of-the-box functions. If you do upgrade, refer [Constructing a Select List with OptGroup groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151572/constructing-a-select-list-with-optgroup-groups) for examples using both the `SelectList` constructor, and by generating an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Without upgrading, you could pass a model representing your groups and their options to the view , and use some javascript/jquery to generate the elements. Start by creating some additional view models

```
public class OptionGroupVM
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OptionVM> Options { get; set; }
}
public class OptionVM
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } // Only applicable if your not binding to a model property
}
```

Then modify your main view model to include the following

```
public class SearchControlViewModel 
{
    ....
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedClasses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OptionGroupVM> ClassOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Note that your current model and use of `ListBoxFor()` is incorrect because

1. you cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects which your `Classes` property is - the model needs to be a collection of value types, and
2. you cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList` - refer [Will there be any conflict if i specify the viewBag name to be equal to the model property name inside @Html.DropDownListFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode) for more detail

In the controller

```
var data = repClass.GetClassesByYear(23);
var groupedOptions = data.GroupBy(x => x.grade).Select(x => new OptionGroupVM()
{
    GroupName = x.Key.ToString(),
    Options = x.Select(y => new OptionVM()
    {
        Value = y.classId.ToString(),
        Text = y.classcame,
    })
});
SearchControlViewModel model = new SearchControlViewModel()
{
    ....
    SelectedClasses = ...., // the values of the options that will be pre-selected
    ClassOptions = groupedOptions
};
return View(model);
```

And in the view use

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => SelectedClasses, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "classList" })
```

which will initially generate the `<select>` without any options. Then use the following script to generate the options

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get data
    var listBox = $('#classList');
    var selected = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SelectedClasses));
    var groups = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ClassOptions));

    // Generate options
    createGroupedOptions(listBox, selected, groups);
    // Attach plug-in
    listBox.multiselect({ enableClickableOptGroups: true });

    // This function could be in an external js file
    function createGroupedOptions(element, selected, groups) {
        for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            var group = groups[i];
            var groupElement = $('<optgroup></optgroup>').attr('label', group.GroupName);
            for(var j = 0; j < group.Options.length; j++) {
                var option = group.Options[j];
                var optionElement = $('<option></option>').val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
                if (selected) {
                    if (selected.toString().indexOf(option.Value) >= 0) {
                        optionElement.attr('selected', 'selected')
                    }
                } else {
                    if (option.IsSelected) {
                        optionElement.attr('selected', 'selected')
                    }
                }

                $(groupElement).append(optionElement);
            }
            $(element).append(groupElement);
        }
    }
</script>
```